# SharePoint deletes by users at times when users are offline

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, recycle-bin

Several users (myself included) have gotten "Heads up!" emails from SharePoint, saying that a large volume of files have been deleted.

The files have been deleted, and it's typically a lot of files, in a 15-minute burst. But it's also happening at times when the user is not online and not logged in. (I can say with some certainty--it happened on my computer at 615a, before I had even turned my computer on for the day).

These 'ghost deletes' are extremely alarming--they are happening for folders and files outside of those typically accessed by users.

Office 365, Exchange license, 34 users (most part-time and semi-active), I'm the company administrator. Not finding anything on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect who deleted those
files firstly.

Reference: https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_detect_who_deleted_file_on_sharepoint.html

Then, check if you have build a flow to delete files automatically on your SharePoint site.
Also, check if you have applied a retention policy to your file.

Comment: That's where it gets weird. In one case, the person who did the delete was me, at a time my computer was powered down.

Comment: Have you checked if you set retention policy or flow to delete files at a certain time?